# vagrant failed to connect VM

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, vagrant

I am running vagrant up command to connect to a VM and while running this command I get below mentioned error.

> I tried several steps as to run it with gui mode ON, but GUI mode
>   itself does not open anything.

while running this command an separate command promt opens and gets closed on its own. 
And after that I get below error.
Can you anyone please give me some idea how can I fix this issues..

**details:** 
OS : windows 7
steps followed are:
1. `vagrant box add box1 c:/vmBoxFolder` - runs fine
2. `vagrant init box1` - runs fine 
3. `vagrant up` - Fails

**host file entries:**
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost

ERROR :

```
C:\blog>vagrant up
[default] VM already created. Booting if its not already running...
[default] Running any VM customizations...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- ssh: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Cleaning previously set shared folders...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] Failed to connect to VM!
Failed to connect to VM via SSH. Please verify the VM successfully booted
by looking at the VirtualBox GUI.
```

thanks,
lucky.

Comment: run vagrant up (or reload) prefixed by VAGRANT_LOG=INFO and past detailed output here. Probably you have different driver version for VB. I had similar issue on OS X and vagrant box prepared for 2.1.x VB while installed 2.2.4

Answer (score 3):

During `Vagrant Up` your Windows system tries to connect to SSH. If you type on your command line:

```
set VAGRANT_LOG=INFO
```

You may see it fail and try a couple of times. It looks like this:

```
INFO ssh: Connecting to SSH: 127.0.0.1:2222
```

This is happening because the timeout is set to 10. This can be modified by placing the following in your Vagrantfile:

```
config.ssh.timeout = 300
```

You can use any number you like but I recommend something above 100.

Sources:

1. [This guy had some useful troubleshooting information.](http://devops.me/2011/10/10/vagrant-tricks-and-troubleshooting/)
2. [Vagrant Docs for Vagrantfiles](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/ssh/timeout.html)
3. [Vagrant Docs for Vagrantfile SSH Timeout](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/ssh/timeout.html)
4. [Vagrant Docs for Debugging](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/debugging.html)
5. [Hours of Troubleshooting (Keep Smilin')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofthf.gif)