# Vagrant stuck in "Waiting for VM to Boot"

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I want to preface this question by mentioning that I have indeed looked over most if not all vagrant "Waiting for VM to Boot" troubleshooting threads:

**Things I've tried include:**

1. [vagrant failed to connect VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261402/vagrant-failed-to-connect-vm)
2. https://superuser.com/questions/342473/vagrant-ssh-fails-with-virtualbox
3. https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/410
4. http://vagrant.wikia.com/wiki/Usage
5. http://scotch.io/tutorials/get-vagrant-up-and-running-in-no-time

And more.

**Here's how I setup my Vagrant:**

Note: We are using Vagrant 1.2.2 since we do not at the moment have time to change configs to newer versions. I am also using VirtualBox 4.2.26.

1. My office has an `/official/` folder which includes things such as `Vagrantfile` inside. Inside my `Vagrantfile` are these custom settings:

> ```
>   config.vm.box = "my_box"
>
>   config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/github_rsa"
>   config.ssh.forward_agent = true
>   config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
>   config.ssh.max_tries = 300
>   config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "/etc/init.d/networking restart"
> ```

2. I installed our custom box (called `package.box`) via `vagrant box add my_box absolute_path/package.box` which went without a hitch.
3. Running `vagrant up`, I would look at the "preview" of the VirtualBox, and it would simply be stuck at the login page. My Terminal would also only say: `Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.` As far as I know, this is an SSH issue. Or my private key issues, though in my `Vagrantfile` I explicitly pointed to my private key location.

**Interesting Notes:**

1. Running `dhclient` within the VirtualBox GUI, it says command no found. Running `sudo dhclient eth0` was one of the suggested fixes.
2. This fix: https://superuser.com/a/343775/298915 of "modify the `/etc/rc.local` file to include the line `sh /etc/init.d/networking restart` just before `exit 0`." did nothing to fix the issue.

**Conclusion:**

Having tried to re-install everything thinking I messed up a file, it did not seem to ameliorate the issue. I am unable to work with this issue. Could someone give me some insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after around twelve hours of dejected troubleshooting, I was able to (finally) get the VM to boot.

1. [Setup your private/public keys](http://jayunit100.blogspot.com/2014/04/insecure-keys-for-devtest-ssh.html) using the link provided. My box is a `Debian Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64`, so instead of `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, you have to use `/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (and the respective `id_rsa` path for the private key).

   Note: make sure your files have the right permissions. Check using `ls -l path`, and change using `chmod`. Your machine may not have `/home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys`, so generate that file with `touch /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
2. Boot your VM using the VirtualBox GUI using (through either `Vagrantfile` boot-GUI command, or starting your VM using VirtualBox). Login using `vagrant` and `vagrant` when prompted.
3. Within the GUI, manually start dhclient using `sudo dhclient eth0 -v`. **Why is it off by default? I have no idea.** I found out that it was off when I tried to `wget` the private/public keys in the tutorial above, but was unable to.
4. Go to your local machine's command line and reload vagrant using `vagrant reload`. It should boot, and no longer hang at "Waiting for VM to Boot."

This worked for me. Though it may be different for other machines, for whatever reason Vagrant likes to break.

Suggestion: can this be saved as a script so we don't need to manually do this everytime?

EDIT: Update to the latest version of Vagrant, and you will never see this issue again. About time, huh?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. Just saved me a bunch of time. One thing to watch out for in my case: the first time I ran `vagrant reload` still got hung up in the first step. I manually shut down the VM in the VirtualBox GUI and then `vagrant reload` worked. No idea why.